# Porting domain to raspberry pi server

Tags: python, linux, networking, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm running a Flask app installed on my Rasperry pi and I am able to access it via the local network at the internal IP and port 8080 (192.168.0.21:8080). I am now trying to access it externally from the network.

I have a netgear router that I've setup to forward port 8080 to 192.168.0.21 (my raspberry pi's internal IP). When I visit aaa.bb.cc.dd:8080 (my external IP) I don't see anything, what am I doing wrong here?

This is the line I am using to start the app from my raspberry pi:

```
app.run(host='192.168.0.21', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Ideally I would like to have a subdomain on a domain that I own point at this app, would I basically just point the A record for that subdomain at my external IP?

**Update**

I've since tried several different ports (ie. 8910, 87, 22) and forwarded these to my raspberry pi's internal IP still to no avail :/ I've even taken a step back and made a super simple hello world app and I am still not having any luck

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello world'

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8910, debug=True)
```

My router forwarding settings are below:
[image]

And then I am basically going to aa.bb.cc.dd:8910 (where aa.bb.cc.dd equals my external ip).

I've also tried porting port 8000 to 80 and then forwarding it to the pi and still nothing.
[image]

**Solution**

I ended up porting the external port 80 to internal port 8000 at the static IP address for my raspberry pi and then running the raspberry pi server on port 8000. I then forwarded my sub-domain to my external IP address and voila!

[image]

Comment: Try `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)` although you should set `debug` to `False` for security reasons.

Comment: I tried this and I am still able to access via my local network but not via an externally connected device (my iphone not connected to the wifi). Is it possible that my ISP is blocking specific ports?

Comment: @JoeyOrlando It is possible, but not very likely that they would block 8910 port. Also, this question has nothing to do with the flask and python, and it's very much router/ISP specific.